# How to do groupBy and filter based on maxDate record in Java List

Tags: java, arrays, scala, arraylist

I have a java POJO for collecting metics like below :

```
public class Metric {

    Long metricId;
    Long resultKeyId;
    @NonNull DatasetType datasetType;
    @NonNull String datasetName;
    @NonNull String analyzerName;
    @NonNull String constraintAlias;
    @NonNull LocalDateTime entityDate;
    @NonNull long entityDurationSec;
    @NonNull Double metricValue;
    @NonNull String changedBy;
    Long jobId = 0L;
    Long codeArtifactId = 0L;
    LocalDateTime createdAt;
    LocalDateTime lastChanged;

}
```

I have a list of metrics from the above pojo like  `List<Metric> metrics`

Now this list can have multiple items and i want to select only one record for the same `resultKeyId,datasetType,datasetName,analyzerName,constraintAlias` with the max `createdAt`

The SQL Representation of this would be something like :

```
select a.* from 
dataval_metric a 
join dataval_metric b 
on a.result_key_id=b.result_key_id 
and a.dataset_type=b.dataset_type 
and a.dataset_name=b.dataset_name 
and a.analyzer_name=b.analyzer_name 
and a.constraint_alias=b.constraint_alias  
where a.result_key_id = 434 
and a.mysql_row_created_at >= b. mysql_row_created_at;
```

Looking for pointers to understand how this can be done in a performant way in Java

Comment: I don't believe this SQL does what you want, for example if there are 3 records and one of them is greater than other twos, the query returns the same record twice. And if, for example, all of the records have the same created date, this query returns nothing I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `gropingBy` method using the fields as key.

The key can be:

1. a **List**:

```java
Map<List<Object>, Optional<Metric>> map = metrics.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m ->
                        List.of(m.getResultKeyId(),
                                m.getDatasetType(),
                                m.getDatasetName(),
                                m.getAnalyzerName(),
                                m.getConstraintAlias()),
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Metric::getCreatedAt))));
```

2. **an object of type Metric** if you override the method `equals` and `hashCode` based just on the fields you want:

```java
Map<Metric, Optional<Metric>> map = metrics.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m,
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Metric::getCreatedAt))));
```

3. **another object with `equals` and `hascode` overridden** like Quintent of the library [javatuples](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.javatuples/javatuples/latest/org/javatuples/Quintet.html)

```java
Map<Quintet, Optional<Metric>> map = metrics.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m ->
                        new Quintet(m.getResultKeyId(),
                                m.getDatasetType(),
                                m.getDatasetName(),
                                m.getAnalyzerName(),
                                m.getConstraintAlias()),
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Metric::getCreatedAt))));
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use `Collectors.toMap`, which maps the key represented as a record `MetricKey` (basically this is just a tuple of the fields you need to group by) to a `Metric`. Since `toMap` doesn't allow duplicates, we also provide the merge function which always keeps metric with a maximum `createdDate` in the map.

So I would propose to add the `getKey` method to the `Metric` class so that it returns the key as a record or as a custom class which overrides `equals` and `hashCode`.

```
class Metric
{
  // ... all your fields
   
  record MetricKey(Long resultKeyId, String analyzerName,
       DatasetType datasetType, String datasetName, String constraintAlias) {  }
   
  public MetricKey getKey() {
    return new MetricKey(resultKeyId, datasetType, datasetName,
       analyzerName, constraintAlias);
  }

  public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
  }
}
```

And the data processing pipeline:

```
List<Metric> maximums = new ArrayList<>(metrics.stream().collect(
  Collectors.toMap(
    Metric::getKey,
    Function.identity(),
    (m1, m2) -> m1.createdAt > m2.createdAt ? m1 : m2))
  .values());
```